Weird jumps in UICollectionViewController with Interactive Keyboard Dismiss
I'm still quite new to UIKit and I'm working on a chat application, similar to Messages, for learning purpose. I've faced an issue when the content of UICollectionView jumps around the top while trying to dismiss the keyboard with the swipe. It happens only when the content is scrolled down from the very top of UICollectionView so that there's a gap between the content and the top of the view.
Here is what it looks like:

I use UICollectionViewController as a view controller and override its inputAccessoryView property with my custom input view (which is just a UIView with UITextView in it).
I've tested it on different devices and simulators with iOS 16 and 17 and I've noticed that this only happens on the devices that have safe area at the bottom (iPhone 15  and iPhone) and doesn't seem to occur on devices without it (iPhone 8 and SE). It makes me think it has something to do with the inputAccessoryView changing its size dynamically to satisfy the safeAreaLayoutGuide constraint. However, even if it is caused by that, I don't know how to make it work properly and achieve the same smooth behaviour as Messages has.
Here's the code for my UICollectionViewController:
class PlaygroundViewController: UICollectionViewController {
    init() {
        super.init(collectionViewLayout: layout)
        collectionView.register(PlaygroundCellView.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "cell")
        collectionView.keyboardDismissMode = .interactive
    }
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        becomeFirstResponder()
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
    
    lazy var playgroundInputView: UIView = { PlaygroundInputView(frame: .zero) }()
    override var canBecomeFirstResponder: Bool { true }
    override var inputAccessoryView: UIView? { playgroundInputView }
}

And here's the custom input view:
class PlaygroundInputView: UIView {
    lazy var textView: UITextView = {
        var view = UITextView()
        view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.backgroundColor = .systemGray6
        view.isScrollEnabled = false
        return view
    }()
    
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        
        self.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleHeight, .flexibleWidth]
        self.backgroundColor = .systemGray3
        
        addSubview(textView)
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            textView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leadingAnchor, constant: 12),
            textView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: trailingAnchor, constant: -12),
            textView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topAnchor, constant: 8),
            textView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor, constant: -8),
        ])
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
    
    override var intrinsicContentSize: CGSize { .zero }
}

Is this even a correct approach? Most of the answers I found online suggest doing it like this (or with slight modifications that don't change much) but I can't get rid of these weird jumps.
I have tried using just a simple UIViewController instead of UICollectionViewController but it adds a lot more problems and I have to handle contentInset manually which makes the behaviour even worse.
I've also tried using inputAccessoryViewController with the similar view inside and inputView?.allowsSelfSizing = true, but the behaviour stayed the same.
A lot of the other things I've tried didn't bring anything good, so I won't even mention them. Hope someone can help me with this.

@Rob I'm aiming at iOS 16+. Could you please tell me about the alternatives?

For iOS 15 and later, I use the keyboardLayoutGuide. See below.

Personally, I tired of all of the idiosyncrasies of input accessory views. In iOS 15 and later, I use a UIViewController and add the collection view and input view as subviews of the main view, and then pin the bottom of the input view to the top main view‘s keyboardLayoutGuide, and you are done. This will animate changes in the input view position (and thus the collection view size, too) gracefully as the keyboard appears and disappears.
func configureViews() {
    collectionView = …
    customInputView = …
    collectionView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    customInputView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

    view.addSubview(collectionView)
    view.addSubview(customInputView)

    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
        collectionView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor),
        collectionView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: customInputView.topAnchor),
        customInputView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.keyboardLayoutGuide.topAnchor),

        collectionView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.leadingAnchor),
        collectionView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.trailingAnchor),
        customInputView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.leadingAnchor),
        customInputView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.trailingAnchor)
    ])

    …
}

 

In case you are interested, here is a MRE:
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    private var messages: [Message] = []

    private var collectionView: UICollectionView!
    private lazy var customInputView = InputView(delegate: self)
    private var keyboardWillShowObserver: NSObjectProtocol?
    private var dataSource: UICollectionViewDiffableDataSource<Section, Message>!

    private var isLastVisible = false

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        configure()
    }

    deinit {
        NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self)
    }
}

// MARK: - Private configuration methods

private extension ViewController {
    func configure() {
        populateModel()
        configureViews()
        configureCollectionView()
        addKeyboardObservers()
    }

    func populateModel() {
        let formatter = NumberFormatter()
        formatter.numberStyle = .spellOut

        messages = (0..<40).map { i in
            Message(string: formatter.string(for: i)!)
        }
    }

    func configureViews() {
        collectionView = UICollectionView(frame: .zero, collectionViewLayout: createLayout())
        collectionView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        customInputView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        view.addSubview(collectionView)
        view.addSubview(customInputView)

        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            collectionView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor),
            collectionView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: customInputView.topAnchor),
            customInputView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.keyboardLayoutGuide.topAnchor),

            collectionView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.leadingAnchor),
            collectionView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.trailingAnchor),
            customInputView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.leadingAnchor),
            customInputView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.trailingAnchor)
        ])

        customInputView.becomeFirstResponder()
    }

    func configureCollectionView() {
        collectionView.register(CollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: CollectionViewCell.reuseIdentifier)
        configureCollectionViewDataSource()
        collectionView.keyboardDismissMode = .interactive
        collectionView.delegate = self
    }

    func createLayout() -> UICollectionViewLayout {
        let itemSize = NSCollectionLayoutSize(
            widthDimension: .fractionalWidth(1),
            heightDimension: .fractionalHeight(1)
        )
        let item = NSCollectionLayoutItem(layoutSize: itemSize)

        let groupSize = NSCollectionLayoutSize(
            widthDimension: .fractionalWidth(1),
            heightDimension: .estimated(44)
        )
        let group = NSCollectionLayoutGroup.horizontal(layoutSize: groupSize, repeatingSubitem: item, count: 1)
        let spacing = CGFloat(5)
        group.interItemSpacing = .fixed(spacing)

        let section = NSCollectionLayoutSection(group: group)
        section.interGroupSpacing = spacing
        section.contentInsets = NSDirectionalEdgeInsets(top: 5, leading: 10, bottom: 5, trailing: 10)

        let layout = UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout(section: section)
        return layout
    }

    func configureCollectionViewDataSource() {
        dataSource = .init(collectionView: collectionView) { collectionView, indexPath, item in
            let cell = CollectionViewCell.dequeue(in: collectionView, for: indexPath)
            cell.configure(for: item.string)
            return cell
        }

        collectionView.dataSource = dataSource

        updateDataSource()
    }

    func updateDataSource() {
        var snapshot = NSDiffableDataSourceSnapshot<Section, Message>()
        snapshot.appendSections([.main])
        snapshot.appendItems(messages)
        dataSource.apply(snapshot)
    }

    func scrollToLastItem(animated: Bool = true) {
        collectionView.scrollToItem(at: IndexPath(item: messages.count - 1, section: 0), at: .bottom, animated: animated)
    }

    func addKeyboardObservers() {
        keyboardWillShowObserver = NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(
            forName: UIResponder.keyboardWillShowNotification,
            object: nil,
            queue: .main
        ) { [weak self] notification in
            guard let self else { return }
            if isLastVisible {
                scrollToLastItem()
            }
        }
    }

}

// MARK: - UICollectionViewDelegate

// Observe cells being displayed and keep track of whether the first last is visible or not;
// Set `isLastVisible` accordingly, and then when the view changes size, make sure to scroll to
// the last one if it was previously displayed.

extension ViewController: UICollectionViewDelegate {
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, willDisplay cell: UICollectionViewCell, forItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        if indexPath == IndexPath(item: messages.count - 1, section: 0) {
            isLastVisible = true
        }
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didEndDisplaying cell: UICollectionViewCell, forItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        if indexPath == IndexPath(item: messages.count - 1, section: 0) {
            isLastVisible = false
        }
    }
}

// MARK: - UITextViewDelegate

extension ViewController: InputViewDelegate {
    func didSend(text: String) {
        messages.append(Message(string: text))
        updateDataSource()
        scrollToLastItem()
    }
}

// MARK: - Section

extension ViewController {
    enum Section {
        case main
    }
}

// MARK: - Message

extension ViewController {
    struct Message: Hashable, Identifiable {
        let id = UUID()
        let string: String
    }
}

class CollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    static let reuseIdentifier = "CollectionViewCell"

    let label = UILabel()

    override init(frame: CGRect = .zero) {
        super.init(frame: frame)

        contentView.backgroundColor = .systemGray6
        contentView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.systemGray2.cgColor
        contentView.layer.borderWidth = 1
        contentView.layer.cornerRadius = 5

        label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        label.numberOfLines = 0

        addSubview(label)
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            label.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leadingAnchor, constant: 10),
            label.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: trailingAnchor, constant: -10),
            label.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topAnchor, constant: 5),
            label.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomAnchor, constant: -5)
        ])
    }

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError()
    }

    override func prepareForReuse() {
        super.prepareForReuse()
        label.text = nil
    }

    static func dequeue(in collectionView: UICollectionView, for indexPath: IndexPath) -> CollectionViewCell {
        collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: Self.reuseIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! CollectionViewCell
    }

    func configure(for text: String) {
        label.text = text
    }
}

protocol InputViewDelegate: AnyObject {
    func didSend(text: String)
}

class InputView: UIView {
    weak var delegate: InputViewDelegate?

    lazy var textView: UITextView = {
        var view = UITextView()
        view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.backgroundColor = .systemGray6
        view.isScrollEnabled = false
        return view
    }()

    init(frame: CGRect = .zero, delegate: InputViewDelegate? = nil) {
        self.delegate = delegate
        super.init(frame: frame)

        configure()
    }

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    @discardableResult
    override func becomeFirstResponder() -> Bool {
        textView.becomeFirstResponder()
    }

    override var canBecomeFirstResponder: Bool { true }
}

private extension InputView {
    func configure() {
        backgroundColor = .systemGray3

        addSubview(textView)
        textView.delegate = self

        let bottom = textView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor, constant: -8)
        bottom.priority = .defaultHigh

        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            textView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leadingAnchor, constant: 12),
            textView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: trailingAnchor, constant: -12),
            textView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topAnchor, constant: 8),
            bottom
        ])
    }
}

extension InputView: UITextViewDelegate {
    func textView(_ textView: UITextView, shouldChangeTextIn range: NSRange, replacementText text: String) -> Bool {
        if text == "\n" {
            if
                let text = textView.text?.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines),
                !text.isEmpty
            {
                delegate?.didSend(text: text)
                textView.text = ""
            }

            return false // Prevent the newline character from being added
        }
        return true
    }
}


Thanks for the suggestions. I've tried this approach before and it doesn't have those weird jumps. However, it creates even more new issues. Now, when I try to hide the keyboard with swipe while the content is way below the top edge, when the keyboard reaches the bottom, the content immediately moves to the zero position, without any animation. It doesn't look very good and I don't know if I like it more than those jumps.

Another issue is that the area where the swipe starts now begins at the top of the keyboard, excluding the input view. It's not a big deal but also doesn't feel right, and can cause difficulties for the user if the input view gets too big.

Regarding the jumping around, yeah, that was a mistake. I've fixed that in my answer above. Regarding the area where swipe is recognized as dismissal of keyboard, yes, that is the tradoff of this approach.
